# An internal error occurred while processing dirty regions

Tags: java, eclipse, regions

I got this error message in Eclipse today:

[image]

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I meant to post this as a CW, but apparently that's gone now?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Any plugin installed? (WTP?)

Comment: Sounds like a personal problem

Comment: @VonC: Eclipse 3.6.1. Lots of plugins, including WTP 3.2.2.v201008170029-7H7AFUQDxumQGOpBqffOY2f1qxDZ. And yes, I was looking at an XML file in Eclipse when this happened.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a lot of plugins break if Eclipse's file cache gets out of sync with the file system.  Try doing an F5 refresh of your entire workspace and see if the problem goes away.

**EDIT**

My general approach with this sort of thing is to try to ignore it.  IMO, it is only worth looking into the cause of problems that *significantly* interfere with your ability to do real work.  Fortunately, most Eclipse bugs don't fall into that category ...

Answer (score 1):

Some plugin has a bug that causes a `NullPointerException`, where the exception may even occur somewhere else in Eclipse. (I've had a similar problem with the Scala IDE breaking Java refactoring.)

You can try uninstalling suspicious plugins until the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens to me, it is usually because I renamed an xml file using Refactor-->Rename and neglected to add the .xml file extension.